# Item is full width on page load before it goes to normal size

Tags: css, sass

I have an item on the page that when loaded, it is full width of the page and then it goes to the size that I would like (A circle). This happens really quickly, and is kind of annoying. Is there any way for me to get the item to load properly?

https://jsfiddle.net/esr6vLbq/11/ (pressing run on jsfiddle does not make it happen you have to refresh the entire browser)

This is the SCSS that I am using:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

.fab {
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex; 
  background-color: red;
  color: white;

  &.fab-lg > i {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

And this is the related html:

```
<a href="" class="fab fab-lg"><i class="material-icons">autorenew</i></a>
```

Maybe this is from the `.material-icons` css, if so here is the code:

```
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is because of the delay in the font loading from google. Its causing it to say autorenew (much wider than the icon) before switching to the icon after loading the font file.

There are two possible solutions. You could set a max-width and max-height along with overflow hidden for the button.

```
.fab {
    max-width: 48px;
    max-height: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or you could use the other implementation of the loop icon.

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE028;</i>
```

Of course, this causes the opposite problem (loads too small at first). Its less noticeable than the larger one but can still be seen. You could do the same thing here except use min-widths and min-heights.